# OMSA Add new disk and convert current single disk to RAID1

Tags: raid, storage, dell-poweredge

We got our new server last week, and unfortunately one of the two disks could not be delivered. Now we've got the second disk, and I want to install it and join it with the current disk to create a RAID1 virtual disk.

Specs:

- Server: Dell PowerEdge R620
- RAID Controller: PERC h710 Mini

My questions are as follows:

1. Can I just insert the disk without shutting down?
2. Is it possible to do this through the OMSA UI?
3. Can I do this without loosing the data currently on the single disk?

As you might have guessed, I'm not an IT-pro (I'm a developer actually), so I might have missed some vital info here. If so, please point it out!

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the disk, if your system is hot-pluggable (R620 should be).

If you set up your single disk as raid1 with a failed second member, you just need to insert the second disk.

If you did it any other way things will get more complicated, but - yes, you can rebuild raids online using OMSA.

So again yes, you can do it without loosing data on the existent single disk.

Apart from that: Backing up systems to external storage should always be done in a professional environment.

Comment: PERCs don't always just pick a drive up and bring it into a faulty array, you might need to set the drive as hotspare for that.

Answer (score 3):

Nils is correct, this operation is supported on all RAID controllers that ship in an R620. You'll need to use the "reconfigure" task on the virtual disk, and change your RAID type to 1 (assuming the single disk is labeled as being a RAID0 currently). Then OpenManage should prompt you to select the additional drive(s) to add that are necessary to make the change.

Typically, OMSA will not allow you to use the virtual disk "reconfigure" task to perform any operation that would wipe out your data, though I can't guarantee that 100%

See the OMSA guide (p230 in this version I'm linking) for the virtual disk reconfigure task info:
ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_software/esuprt_ent_sys_mgmt/dell-opnmang-srvr-admin-v7.2_User's%20Guide2_en-us.pdf